# Python баг на tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Имеем баг: при нажатие на "Вот эта кнопка" кнопку ткинтер не реагирует, но при нажатие на кнопку Add родительского окна, он тут же выводит, то, что должно выводится при нажатие на "Вот эта кнопка" кнопку. Я понятия не имею как это получилось...

```
from tkinter import *


class Notificator:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.configure(width=320, height=200)
        self.root.title('Notificator')
        self.words = ['opposition = оппозиция', 'crossroads = перекрёстки', 'game = игра']
        self.iterator = iter(self.words)
        self.main()

    def iter(self):
        try:
            self.next_word = next(self.iterator)
        except StopIteration:
            self.iterator = iter(self.words)
            self.next_word = next(self.iterator)

        return self.next_word

    def spliter(self, string):
        self.object = str(string)
        self.two_words = self.object.split('=')

        return self.two_words

    def word_changer(self):
        self.worder = self.spliter(self.iter())
        self.Translate.configure(text='Russian: ' + str(self.worder[1]), font=('family', 20))
        self.Word.config(text=('English: ' + str(self.worder[0])), font=('family', 20))

        self.root.update()

    def add_starter(self):
        self.root.destroy()
        add = AddWord()

    def main(self):
        self.worder = self.spliter(self.iter())
        self.OK = Button(self.root, width=8, height=3, text='Exit', font=('family', 10), command=lambda: self.root.destroy())
        self.OK.place(x=161, y=116)
        self.Word = Label(self.root, text=('English: ' + str(self.worder[0])), font=('family', 20))
        self.Word.place(x=31, y=34)
        self.Translate = Label(self.root, text='Russian: ' + str(self.worder[1]), font=('family', 20))
        self.Translate.place(x=10, y=70)
        self.next = Button(self.root, width=8, height=3, text='Next', command=self.word_changer, font=('family', 10)).place(x=50, y=116)
        self.add = Button(self.root, width=4, height=3, text='Add', command=self.add_starter)
        self.add.place(x=282, y=0)
        self.root.mainloop()


class AddWord:
    def __init__(self):
        self.two = Tk()
        self.two.config(height=200, width=400)
        self.two.title('Add a word')
        self.main()

    def main(self):
        self.ButtOK = Button(self.two, width=8, height=3, text='Exit', command=self.back_to_main)
        self.ButtOK.place(x=120, y=100)
        self.stringer = StringVar()
        self.stringer2 = StringVar()
        self.Enttry = Entry(self.two, textvariable=self.stringer).place(x=150, y=20)
        self.Enttry1 = Entry(self.two, textvariable=self.stringer2).place(x=150, y=60)
        self.ButtOK = Button(self.two, width=8, height=3, text='Вот эта кнопка', command=self.adddereder()).place(x=220, y=100)
        self.Label1 = Label(self.two, text='English:', font=('arial', 20)).place(x=40, y=9)
        self.Label2 = Label(self.two, text='Russin:', font=('arial', 20)).place(x=40, y=47)
        self.two.mainloop()

    def adddereder(self):
        print('Выводит это сообщение при нажатие на Add главного окна, а должен при нажатии на дочернем ')

    def back_to_main(self):
        self.two.destroy()
        Main_window = Notificator()

Main_window = Notificator()
```

Comment: Исходник на GitHub: https://github.com/personality13/tkinter_software/blob/master/Notificator.py

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обратите внимание на вот эту строку в методе `main` класса `AddWord`:

```
self.ButtOK = Button(self.two, width=8, height=3, text='Вот эта кнопка',
                     command=self.adddereder()).place(x=220, y=100)
```

Здесь вы в параметр `command` передаете не метод `self.adddereder`, а вызываете метод, и передаете в `command` результат вызова метода (`command=self.adddereder()`).

Таким образом, метод вызывается единожды при вызове метода `main` класса `AddWord`, а при нажатии на кнопку "Вот эта кнопка" ничего не происходит, хотя по идее должна быть ошибка `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable`. Почему такой ошибки нет - это уже другой вопрос. Скорее всего tkinter как-то по-своему вызывает обработчики событий, и при попытке вызова значения `None` как функции просто ничего не делает (скорее всего просто считает, что обработчик для данного события не определён).

Чтобы исправить ошибку в вашем коде, достаточно убрать скобки `()` после имени метода `self.adddereder` в указанной выше строке.

Comment: Да, это очень странно, я случайно дописал скобки, хотя надо было указывать место в памяти. Спасибо за ответ

Comment: @personality13, ключевой момент тут - магии не бывает. Если метод вызывается не в тот момент, когда ожидается, то нужно смотреть те места, где используется.